# Using LINQ with Action to delete old files

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to do something like

```
Action<FileInfo> deleter = f =>
    {
        if (....) // delete condition here
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(f.FullName);
        }
    };

DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(_path);

di.GetFiles("*.pdf").Select(deleter); // <= Does not compile!
di.GetFiles("*.txt").Select(deleter); // <= Does not compile!
di.GetFiles("*.dat").Select(deleter); // <= Does not compile!
```

in order to delete old files from a directory. But I do not know how to directly apply the delegate to the FilInfo[] without an explicit foreach (the idea listed above does not work of course).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Select()` is used to *project* items from `TSource` to `TResult`. In your case, you do not need `Select` because you're not projecting. Instead, use `List<T>`s `ForEach` method to delete files:

```
di.GetFiles("*.pdf").ToList().ForEach(deleter);
```

Comment: Does not seem to work, perhaps Panagiotis Kanavos is right in its comment when he says that the expression will not be evaluated until enumerated, so the files will not be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>As DarkGray suggests you could, if somewhat unusually, utilise the `Select` to firstly action the file, and then return a null collection.</strike> I would recommend utilising the `ForEach` extension, like so:

### `ForEach` LINQ Extension

```
public static void ForEach<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach(TSource item in source)
     {
        action(item);
    }
}
```

You should then be able to execute the action on the array of `FileInfo`, as array is an enumerator. Like so:

### Execution

```
Action<FileInfo> deleter = f =>
{
    if (....) // delete condition here
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(f.FullName);
    }
};

DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(_path);
di.GetFiles("*.pdf").ForEach(deleter);
```

*Edit by Richard.*
I do want to raise attention to the argument of `foreach` vs `ForEach`. In my opinion the `ForEach` statement should directly effect the object being passed in, and in this case it does. So I've contradicted myself. Oops! :)

Comment: Obligatory link to [why `IEnumerable<>` wasn't given a `ForEach` extension method](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx)

Comment: @AakashM I agree with the author when says "this is harder to debug", but I think this is not "harder to read".

Answer (score -1):

```
di.GetFiles("*.pdf").Select(_=>{deleter(_);return null;});
```

or

```
di.GetFiles("*.pdf").ForEach(action); 

public static class Hlp
{
 static public void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action)
 {
   foreach (var item in items)
     action(item);
 }
}
```

Comment: It won't compile because `GetFiles` returns an array of `FileInfo` but `ForEach` is definied on `List<T>`, so you're missing a `ToList()` in between.

Comment: I have not the ForEach method, perhaps have been introduced with a recent .NET version?

Comment: ForEach is a static method of Array or an instance method of List<T>. It can't be called in this fashion. What's more, Select will not be called unless the resulting enumerable is enumerated. The files will not be deleted